# Why do I get different results when using goal seek manually and in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I made a spreadsheet to solve Colebrook's equation and it worked pretty well: I used goalseek to solve the equation and obtain the friction factor that I wanted (for a specific set of conditions)
This is the eq:
[image: Colebrook-White equation]

This is what my spreadsheet looks like:
[image: Spreadsheet]

So basically what I do is: set objective (the squared difference of both sides of the equation) to zero by changing the friction factor by using Goal Seek. I set Maximum Change to 0.000001 and it works pretty well.

I then tried to automate this process with VBA to perform the calculations on different flows (ignore column K):

```
Sub Darcy()
'
' Darcy Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+D
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' Disable screen updating for faster execution
Fila = 2
    Do While Range("G" & Fila) <> ""
    Range("G" & Fila).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("C1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("C3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("H" & Fila).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        
    Range("C8").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("I" & Fila).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    Range("C11").Value = 1
    
    With Application
    .MaxIterations = 100
    .MaxChange = 0.000001
    End With
    Range("C14").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("C11")
    
    Range("C11").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("J" & Fila).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        
    Range("K" & Fila).Value = 1
    
    Fila = Fila + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

I was expecting to get similar values to those obtained when performing "manual" calculations.
Goal seek through VBA doesn't take the "Objective" cell close enough to zero and the friction factor thus obtained is not correct.
For the same input as last case, this is what the VBA calculation yields:

[image: VBA solution]

I added the "With Application" block thinking that it was a matter of Maximum Change, but this didn't work out neither.
I was wondering what could be the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: It could be that the value in the changing cell (C11) isn't the same when you run the code vs when you do it manually (see [discussion here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/question-about-goal-seek-returning-different-results.351857/)). Let's say you change the value of the changing cell back to 0 for both cases. Do you get the same answer?